# Hive Date Comparison

Tags: hive

I have the following columns in a Hive table. All the columns are of datatype `string`. Each row is distinct as the other column( 7 or 8 more columns) values have at least one unique value in it. I want to write a Hive query to select the records where `datetime >= 2017-05` and drop records where `datetime < 2017-05`. Here the output of this should be rows with `orderid` - `101, 102, 103`. All records with `orderid` `100` should be dropped. Note: Orderid 100 has 1 record with datetime > 2017-05. Still it should be dropped as it has atleast 1 record with datetime < 2017-05. Orderid could be any 12-16 digit number. The table has billions of records.

Can someone help to write a hive query for this? Thanks in advance.

```
datetime            orderid     other columns
2017-04-30 17:10:05 100 
2017-03-05 12:25:30 100 
2017-05-09 08:18:44 100 
2017-05-15 04:21:43 101 
2017-06-20 11:20:10 101 
2017-05-22 05:09:35 102 
2017-07-01 06:25:30 102 
2017-06-25 08:24:40 103 
2017-05-11 11:50:49 103
```

Output Result:

```
datetime            orderid     other columns

2017-05-15 04:21:43    101 
2017-06-20 11:20:10    101 
2017-05-22 05:09:35    102 
2017-07-01 06:25:30    102 
2017-06-25 08:24:40    103 
2017-05-11 11:50:49    103
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select  *

from   (select  *
               ,min(datetime) over (partition by  orderid) as min_datetime  

        from    mytable
        ) t

where   min_datetime >= '2017-05'
;
```

Comment: Thanks, Dudu Mark.

Comment: Hi Dudu, for some reasons, I'm not getting the correct results from your query...so I modified and got the correct results...I posted the modified query...thanks.

Answer (score 0):

select * 
from (select min(datetime) as date_time, orderid from mytable group by orderid)t 
where date_time>='2017-05%';

Comment: There is no way this returns the output results you have requested